# Determining if a given point is within a defined rectangle

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand why my code for determining whether a point given is within (borders included) or without a rectangle. At the moment I receive a 0 no matter if the point is in or if its not and I'm finding difficulties diagnosing this. Where'd I make a hiccup?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int InRectangle( float pt[2], float rect[4] )
{
    float x=pt[0];
    float y=pt[1];
    float box_x=rect[0];
    float box_y=rect[1];
    float box_x_opp=rect[2];
    float box_y_opp=rect[3];
    float x_diff=0;
    float y_diff=0;

    x_diff = box_x_opp - box_x ;
    y_diff = box_y_opp - box_y;

    //if x_diff is + and y diff is + 
    if (x_diff>=0  && y_diff>=0)
    {
        if ((x >= box_x) && (x <= box_x_opp) && (y>=box_y) && (y<=box_y_opp))
            {return 1;} 
    }
    //if x_diff is - and y diff is -

    if (x_diff<0  && y_diff<0)
    {
        if ((x <= box_x) && (x >= box_x_opp) && (y>=box_y) && (y<=box_y_opp))
            {return 1;} 
    }
    //if x_diff is + and y diff is -

    if (x_diff>=0  && y_diff<0)
    {
        if ((x >= box_x) && (x <= box_x_opp) && (y<=box_y) && (y>=box_y_opp))
            {return 1;} 
    }
    //if x_diff is - and y diff is +
    if (x_diff<0  && y_diff>=0)
    {
        if ((x <= box_x) && (x >= box_x_opp) && (y>=box_y) && (y<=box_y_opp))
            {return 1;} 
    }
    else 
        {return 0;}
}
```

Comment: What are your inputs, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: [1,2] is first arg and [0,0,4,4] is the second argument. Should return 1.

Comment: It returns 1 for me.  Try stepping though line by line with a debugger to see what happens.  Also, not all code paths return a value, and take another look at the conditions for `y` is the second set of conditions.

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding by us humans: follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems massively overcomplicated which is why it is hard to find bugs!

All you need is something like:

```
return x > rect_minx_x && x < rect_max_x && y > rect_min_y && y < rect_max_y;
```

Of course you need to figure out all of those values, but that is trivial.

Comment: Yea looking back on it now it  looks like it was a tad bit unnecessary xD Although i still dont understand why it was incorrect the way i had done it. =/ 

I redid it to reflect your line of thinkning, it was much easier to code for.

Comment: Your original way had so many different paths and conditions. Also, in theory if it made it to the last condition `if (x_diff<0  && y_diff>=0)` and then failed the inner `if`, then the function would exit with no return (since the "default" is embedded in an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition: You forgot to flopp the y point checks in 2nd if case:

```
//if x_diff is - and y diff is -

if (x_diff<0  && y_diff<0)
{
    if ((x <= box_x) && (x >= box_x_opp) && (y>=box_y) && (y<=box_y_opp))
        {return 1;} 
}
```

should be:

```
//if x_diff is - and y diff is -

if (x_diff<0  && y_diff<0)
{
    if ((x <= box_x) && (x >= box_x_opp) && (y <= box_y) && (y >= box_y_opp))
        {return 1;} 
}
```

because in that case `box_x` is bigger or equal than `box_x_opp` AND `box_y` is bigger or equal than `box_y_opp`

to get your code more readable, something like

```
float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

if (rect[0] >= rect[2]) {
    xMin = rect[2];
    xMax = rect[0];
} else {
    xMin = rect[0];
    xMax = rect[2];
}

if (rect[1] >= rect[3]) {
    yMin = rect[3];
    yMax = rect[1];
} else {
    yMin = rect[1];
    yMax = rect[3];
}
```

then you can combine it with the [solution by John3136](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36537827/6176654) to solve:

```
return x >= xMin && x <= xMax && y >= yMin && y <= yMax;
```